# Linux bash iterating and Break

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell-script

I have two server groups SERVERS_CA AND SERVERS_NY.

I will have a array something like SERVERGROUP=(CA NY)

CA and NY will have set of servers in arrays like

CA=(ca126 ca546 ca 642)

NY=(ny112 ny113 ny114)

What my script has to do is to check if the HOSTNAME of the server from where we run the script will match which group.

Suppose the HOSTNAME of the server is in CA array then it should say something like SERVERGROUP IS CALIFORNIA

for this script the loop should have break statement and should get out of the loop once the required servergroup is found not to exceute whole loop.

If some one could help me write this script it would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arrays of arrays are really quite painful in bash

```
host=ny113
for grp in "${SERVERGROUP[@]}"; do 
    ref="${grp}[@]"
    for srv in "${!ref}"; do 
        if [[ $host == $srv ]]; then 
            echo $host is in $grp
            break 2
        fi
    done
done
```

```
ny113 is in NY
```

Using associative arrays (bash version 4) is another approach:

```
declare -A grps
grps[CA]="ca126 ca546 ca 642"
grps[NY]="ny112 ny113 ny114"

for grp in "${!grps[@]}"; do 
    # all quotes and spaces are very deliberate in next command
    if [[ " ${grps[$grp]} " == *" $host "* ]]; then
        echo $host is in $grp
        break
    fi
done
```

Or, you could build a "reverse map"

```
declare -A host2group
for grp in "${SERVERGROUP[@]}"; do 
    ref="${grp}[@]"
    for srv in "${!ref}"; do 
        host2group[$srv]=$grp
    done
done
echo $host is in ${host2group[$host]}
```

```
ny113 is in NY
```

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about breaking the loops early. That will be far from the biggest performance bottleneck.