# ksh script using if break statements

Tags: unix, shell-script, ksh

I have a script file that has the server details like

```
set -A SERVERGRPS SERVERS_CA SERVERS_NY
set -A CA ca126 ca546 ca 642
set -A NY ny112 ny113 ny114
```

now I have to write a another script which shouldn't have any server details hard coded it shouldn't display any server names it should use the first script file that I have pasted above It just has to display the server group at the end by using the $HOSTNAME of the server from where we run the script (It will match which group like CA or NY).

Suppose the HOSTNAME of the server is in CA array then it should say something like SERVERGROUP IS CALIFORNIA. If no server name matches in both the arrays it should display "no server name matched".

for this script the loop should have break statement and should get out of the loop once the required servergroup is found not to exceute whole loop.

```
for TEMP_SRVGRP in ${SERVERGRPS[*]}; do
SERVERGRP="GRP_$TEMP_SRVGRP"
for SERVERGRP in ${SERVERGRP_TEMP[*]}; do
if [[ $SERVERGRP == $HOSTNAME ]]; then 
        $SERVERGRPS=$SERVERGRP
break
        echo $SERVERGRPS
    fi
  done
done
 if [[ -n $SERVERGRPS]]; then
   break
  fi
  if [[ -z $SERVERGRPS]]; then
echo SERVERGRP is not defined for $HOSTNAME
fi
```

done

If some one could help me write this script it would be great. Please Help me....

Comment: Aside from ksh, how is this different from your [previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/803913/linux-bash-iterating-and-break)? This site is not a "give me teh codez" service, see http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello Glenn I have wrote the above script I'm unable to get the desired output.